# CSS3 Animation Text Colour Change

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS3 and trying to learn but also could apply it to a project that i am working on. I think i am not far off but it just the last bit i am stuck on.

What i want to achieve is the letters change to the alternative colour then go back to there original colour but it loops through the letters one by one

i.e. letter A goes Dark Blue => light Blue => Dark Blue
Letter B goes Light Blue => Dark Blue => Light Blue

[image]

This is the code i have got so far

```css
body
{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 background: #FFFFFF;
}

ul
{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: flex;
}

ul li
{
 list-style:none;
 
 font-size: 5em;
 letter-spacing: 15px;
 
}

ul li.A
{
  color: #3D57A7;
  animation: aniA 1.4s linear infinite;
}

ul li.B
{
 color: #95D1D7;
  animation: aniB 3s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 1.6s;
}

@keyframes aniA
{
 0%, 90%
 {
 color: #3D57A7;
 }

 100%
 {
 color: #95D1D7;
 }
}

@keyframes aniB
{
 0%, 90%
 {
  color: #95D1D7;
 }
 100%
 {
  color: #3D57A7;
 }
}

ul li:nth-child(1), ul li:nth-child(10)
{
 animation-delay: .2s;
}

ul li:nth-child(2), ul li:nth-child(11)
{
 animation-delay: .4s;
}

ul li:nth-child(3), ul li:nth-child(12)
{
 animation-delay: .6s;
}

ul li:nth-child(4), ul li:nth-child(13)
{
 animation-delay: .8s;
}

ul li:nth-child(5), ul li:nth-child(14)
{
 animation-delay: 1s;
}

ul li:nth-child(6), ul li:nth-child(15)
{
 animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

ul li:nth-child(7)
{
 animation-delay: 1.4s;
}

ul li:nth-child(8)
{
 animation-delay: 1.6s;
}

ul li:nth-child(9)
{
 animation-delay: 3s;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="A">A</li>
<li class="A">A</li>
<li class="A">A</li>
<li class="A">A</li>
<li class="A">A</li>
<li class="A">A</li>
<li class="A">A</li>
<li class="A">A</li>
<li> </li>
<li class="B">B</li>
<li class="B">B</li>
<li class="B">B</li>
<li class="B">B</li>
<li class="B">B</li>
<li class="B">B</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way you could do it, and save (*a few rules :)*

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
}
ul::after,
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 4em;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
ul li.A {
  color: #3D57A7;
}
ul li.B {
  color: #95D1D7;
}
ul::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;  
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  animation: ani 4s steps(10, end) infinite;
}

@keyframes ani {
   0%       { left: 0; content: 'A'; color: #95D1D7; }
   49.9999% { content: 'A'; color: #95D1D7; }
   50%      { color: #95D1D7; }
   50.0001% { content: 'B'; color: #3D57A7; }
   60%      { content: 'B'; color: #3D57A7; }
   100%     { left: 100%; content: 'B'; color: #3D57A7; }
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="A">A</li>
    <li class="A">A</li>
    <li class="A">A</li>
    <li class="A">A</li>
    <li class="A">A</li>
    
    <li class="B">B</li>
    <li class="B">B</li>
    <li class="B">B</li>
    <li class="B">B</li>
    <li class="B">B</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve my question this is how i achieved it

```css
body
{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 background: #FFFFFF;
}

ul
{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: flex;
}

ul li
{
 list-style:none;
 
 font-size: 5em;
 letter-spacing: 15px;
 
}

ul li.A
{
  color: #3D57A7;
  animation: aniA 2.8s linear infinite;
}

ul li.B
{
 color: #95D1D7;
  animation: aniB 2.8s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes aniA
{
 0%, 90%
 {
 color: #3D57A7;
 }

 100%
 {
 color: #95D1D7;
 }
}

@keyframes aniB
{
 0%, 90%
 {
  color: #95D1D7;
 }
 100%
 {
  color: #3D57A7;
 }
}

ul li:nth-child(1)
{
 animation-delay: .2s;
}

ul li:nth-child(2)
{
 animation-delay: .4s;
}

ul li:nth-child(3)
{
 animation-delay: .6s;
}

ul li:nth-child(4)
{
 animation-delay: .8s;
}

ul li:nth-child(5)
{
 animation-delay: 1s;
}

ul li:nth-child(6)
{
 animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

ul li:nth-child(7)
{
 animation-delay: 1.4s;
}

ul li:nth-child(8)
{
 animation-delay: 1.6s;
}

ul li:nth-child(9)
{
 animation-delay: 2.8s;
}

ul li:nth-child(10)
{
 animation-delay: 1.8s;
}

ul li:nth-child(11)
{
 animation-delay: 2s;
}

ul li:nth-child(12)
{
 animation-delay: 2.2s;
}

ul li:nth-child(13)
{
 animation-delay: 2.4s;
}

ul li:nth-child(14)
{
 animation-delay: 2.6s;
}

ul li:nth-child(15)
{
 animation-delay: 2.8s;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="A">A</li>
<li class="A">A</li>
<li class="A">A</li>
<li class="A">A</li>
<li class="A">A</li>
<li class="A">A</li>
<li class="A">A</li>
<li class="A">A</li>
<li> </li>
<li class="B">B</li>
<li class="B">B</li>
<li class="B">B</li>
<li class="B">B</li>
<li class="B">B</li>
<li class="B">B</li>
</ul>
```